# FB like box not showing

Tags: iframe, facebook-likebox

I have been using the Facebook Like Box in this template, it's showing good in opera, IE, and Firefox. But its not showing in chrome and safari, just showing a blank space. Bottom right section, under the *meet us on title*.

Please click this [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/101570127/oDesk_job/artist_temp5/index.html)

Comment: show some code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using https:// protocol to load the iframe

so you will have:

```
<iframe id="facebook" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:314px; height:240px;" src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FFacebookDevelopers&width=314&height=290&colorscheme=dark&show_faces=true&header=true&stream=false&show_border=true"></iframe>
```

Comment: I just took a look at your website and the link is still using http instead of https. Try pasting the code that you wrote to generate the FB box, I should be able to modify it to make it work.